# How to get more detail from remote server for each item got from database

Tags: android, android-room, android-paging

I'm using RecyclerView + PagedListAdapter + Room to show the data in database. It works now.

But I want to get more detail from remote server for each item got from database. How can I do?

Comment: Send an array of items from device to server and get details. Also what's your use case do you want to fetch details on click?

Comment: I cached the data to device database, so I can load from database  to show. but  some detail might change on server side,  I need retrieve the updated part (not the whole record) for each record.

Comment: Is it a general architectural design question or are you looking for a specific implementation?